# Cast every element inserted into a set

Tags: python-3.x, collections, casting, set

I would like to make a subclass of set, which behave like a set, except that every element added should be casted to a given type (and raise Exception if it is not possible).

In this example I show what would be a set whose every element is casted to str. The inner elements can only be str. The element that we add are caste to str. The iterables that we use for update/intersection/difference/union.... are casted to str too.

```
StrCastedSet = CastedSet(str)
mySet = StrCastedSet([1, 2, True, "test"])
print(list(mySet))
>>> ["1", "2", "True", "test"]
print(list(mySet.intersection([2, 3, "test"])))
>>> ["2", "test"]
print(2 in mySet)
>>> True
print((not False) in mySet)
>>> True
print(3 in mySet)
>>> False
```

Of course I could override each method specifically. But I am wondering if maybe I could code some clever decorator that does this. Or even if such a collection is already implemented.

Comment: Use try & except. Can you possibly give a better example?

Comment: My example is not so great, I am doing a better example ! I do not see how I could do this with try/except for now.

Comment: I have changed the example ! Feel free to read the new one :-)